# How to Loop within a Loop (Display Children and then Grandchildren)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to develop a query for WordPress that will allow me to display a list of child pages with titles only, and then under each child page title, a list of grandchilden (children of the child) page titles AND their content.

So for example, the output should be something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>Child Page 1</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Child Page 2</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h3>Grandchild</h3>
            <p>Hello, welcome to this grandchild page</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Grandchild #2</h3>
            <p>Hello, welcome to this grandchild page</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Child Page 3</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It needs to be done dynamically, meaning I do not want to specify the post ID number as part of the query.

I have tried using a standard WordPress Query and then nesting a second query within the first one - this failed.

In addition, I also tried modifying the code seen here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-child-pages-of-a-current-page-and-loop-through-each-child-page

Finally, I also tried to modify this code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {  while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $thispage=$post->ID; }} ?>
<?php $childpages = query_posts('post_per_page=3&orderby=menu_order&order=asc&post_type=' . get_post_type( $post->ID ) . '&post_parent='.$thispage);
    if($childpages){ /* display the children content  */
            foreach ($childpages as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <li><a class="" href="#<?php echo($post->post_name) ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></li>
          <?php
      endforeach;
     } ?>
```

I've been trying to get this working for more than a day now and i'm just going around in circles really.

Would very much appreciate help in getting this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you, it only goes 1 level deep but you should get the gist.

```
echo "<ul>";    
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        echo "<li><h1>".get_the_title()."</h1>";

        $args=array(
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'post_type' => get_post_type( $post->ID ),
                'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

        $childpages = new WP_Query($args);

        if($childpages->post_count > 0) { /* display the children content  */
            echo "<ul>";
            while ($childpages->have_posts()) {
                 $childpages->the_post();
                 echo "<li><h2>".get_the_title()."</h2></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: In order to make it another level deep, would I just create another $args=array etc before the reset query or....?

Comment: Yeah, basically copy/paste from $args=array( to wp_reset_query(); to go after echo "<li><h2>".get_the_title()."</h2></li>";

Answer (score 0):

I tried something of a sort and went several levels deep.

```
Page 1
|
|-Child 1
|
|-Child 2
    |
    |-Grand child 1
    |
    |-Grand child 2
        |
        |-Great grand child 1
        |
        |-Great grand child 2
```

The full code is at this link
https://gist.github.com/bahiirwa/3aee9cd7732b1f438dfcb5909075cc61